Discord bio change using HTTP API
I want to change my Discord bio. I have this program:
import requests

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": token
}

new_bio = {
    "bio": "new bio text"
}

url_api_info = "https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me"
response = requests.patch(url_api_info, headers=headers, json=new_bio)

It gets information, but I'm not sure how to change it.
I tried to read the API, but I didn't see anything.

“It gets informations” What gets what information? See [ask]

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try using this api url instead.
https://discord.com/api/v9/users/%40me/profile

This should fix the problem.
